# TypeScript: Using jQuery causes an ReferrenceError

Tags: javascript, typescript

I try to use TypeScript. As a former javascript user, I dont want to give up on jQuery.

So I searched my through the internet and found a decent amount of websites who explained how to use it. I use Visual Studio 2012

So this is my first attempt:

```
    /// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

class Person {

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    name: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "hallo " + person.name;
}

var person = new Person("bert");


$(document).ready(function () {
    var message = greeter(person);
    jQuery("#content")[0].innerHTML = message;
});
```

I can build the solution, but if I open my website, it got an javascript error:

ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: Dumb question but, are you loading jQuery on your page? You're only referencing the jQuery definition, it's not actually being compiled with your .ts, so you still need to add it in a script tag.

Comment: newbie tuesday... thanks for the help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to still load jquery.js (e.g. with a script tag), just like if you weren't using TypeScript.