# External scripts not included

Tags: typescript

I'm running into this issue with typescript.

In my file I start with:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../js/lib/Wf.Ajax.Client.js"/>

   declare var $;
    module Wf{
     export module utilities{
      export class CodesList{
       private client;
        constructor(){
         this.client = new Wf.Ajax.Client();
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

This gives me the error `Unresolved variable ajax`

Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Using jQuery causes an ReferrenceError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494197/typescript-using-jquery-causes-an-referrenceerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the external JavaScript library manually, either via a `script` tag or some module loader like requireJS.

`///<reference` comments are only for typescript files so : `/// <reference path="../../js/lib/Wf.Ajax.Client.js"/>` is invalid.